# Application error in django app with heroku

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, heroku

I have a problem with django and heroku , I do all the process in the right way , but when I load the page appears the view of Application Error , I go to the logs, and do not quite understand where the mistake or how to correct it.

```
2016-03-30T18:03:43.554937+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug 
compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:05:38.020807+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:05:38.020812+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:13:16.747238+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:13:16.747248+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:15:25.574991+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:15:25.575001+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:17:39.815473+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:17:39.815481+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:22:20.436789+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:22:20.436848+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:25:49.906296+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:25:49.906304+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:27:54.340115+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:27:54.340124+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:29:37.663978+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:29:37.663986+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:31:55.335354+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:31:55.335363+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:33:39.836240+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:33:39.836249+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:42:02.349925+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:42:02.349930+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:43:39.124391+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:43:39.124396+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Python app
2016-03-30T18:48:00.701770+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE resource by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:48:00.701770+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:48:01.056715+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:48:01.182569+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 24fc830 by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:48:01.182621+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:48:01.574703+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:48:01.574712+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-03-30T18:48:08.163773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn carlos_beta.wsgi`
2016-03-30T18:48:10.568930+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2016-03-30T18:48:11.705004+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-30T18:48:11.685368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-03-30T18:48:11.706091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-03-30T18:48:15.545546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn carlos_beta.wsgi`
2016-03-30T18:48:17.066869+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2016-03-30T18:48:17.747246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-30T18:48:17.735462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-03-30T18:48:37.794053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=c00901cf-1613-4739-b357-1d48956968df fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:48:39.233565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=1a99305a-b356-42ed-bbf5-d5f78538a4ba fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:48:54.413292+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=918fbe60-f099-4c6e-b3fe-9c34f83a6c07 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:48:59.198932+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=180f7cc1-d577-4fbe-b309-19425bde687e fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:49:14.998809+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:49:19.826401+00:00 heroku[run.5139]: Awaiting client
2016-03-30T18:49:20.184551+00:00 heroku[run.5139]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-30T18:49:20.630142+00:00 heroku[run.5139]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2016-03-30T18:49:23.451229+00:00 heroku[run.5139]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-30T18:49:23.479266+00:00 heroku[run.5139]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-30T18:51:24.414393+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:51:30.393578+00:00 heroku[run.3566]: Awaiting client
2016-03-30T18:51:30.438740+00:00 heroku[run.3566]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2016-03-30T18:51:30.691161+00:00 heroku[run.3566]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-30T18:51:34.484817+00:00 heroku[run.3566]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-30T18:51:34.450030+00:00 heroku[run.3566]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-30T18:55:05.802325+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:55:10.230163+00:00 heroku[run.7741]: Awaiting client
2016-03-30T18:55:10.265002+00:00 heroku[run.7741]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2016-03-30T18:55:10.565723+00:00 heroku[run.7741]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-30T18:55:12.736676+00:00 heroku[run.7741]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-30T18:55:12.726511+00:00 heroku[run.7741]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-30T18:56:56.671876+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0f5b8a4 by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:56:56.671876+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:56:56.870891+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-03-30T18:56:56.870902+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-03-30T18:56:57.161583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-03-30T18:57:00.963542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn carlos_beta.wsgi`
2016-03-30T18:57:02.650107+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2016-03-30T18:57:03.413265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-30T18:57:03.393207+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-03-30T18:57:11.589820+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate` by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:57:16.294569+00:00 heroku[run.2397]: Awaiting client
2016-03-30T18:57:16.646754+00:00 heroku[run.2397]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-30T18:57:17.267723+00:00 heroku[run.2397]: Starting process with command `python manage.py migrate`
2016-03-30T18:57:24.765293+00:00 heroku[run.2397]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-30T18:57:24.761367+00:00 heroku[run.2397]: Process exited with status 0
2016-03-30T18:57:35.177421+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createsuperuser` by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T18:57:40.860191+00:00 heroku[run.2080]: Awaiting client
2016-03-30T18:57:40.901207+00:00 heroku[run.2080]: Starting process with command `python manage.py createsuperuser`
2016-03-30T18:57:41.142711+00:00 heroku[run.2080]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-30T18:58:06.353201+00:00 heroku[run.2080]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-30T18:58:06.337391+00:00 heroku[run.2080]: Process exited with status 0
2016-03-30T18:58:30.828068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=3322b71b-93aa-41bc-9ff1-ddaa543a33aa fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:58:31.316668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=c824e1d8-1754-4db8-88b4-257e9b5b6a12 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:58:31.416827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=701bf8a9-a68c-437c-8d1f-a9fb79e92afa fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:58:58.651938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=ed634e64-c10a-4606-8a24-2d138b5a38d8 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T18:58:58.757931+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=37749536-78c1-4bac-834f-d3b478306f76 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T19:00:17.340102+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=a7120143-6a6e-4a92-8860-cc60e15f2776 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T19:00:17.439743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=535656ff-cfc8-4633-932b-00c69d9b4566 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T19:00:25.790846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=33b37e38-69d1-4f69-9081-df9681ae3772 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T19:00:25.974393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=e306bd25-bc3f-4f60-9a25-aec5a91554db fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T19:03:17.993496+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `pip install gunicorn` by guillermo.navarro@tectijuana.edu.mx
2016-03-30T19:03:22.472716+00:00 heroku[run.6010]: Awaiting client
2016-03-30T19:03:22.490861+00:00 heroku[run.6010]: Starting process with command `pip install gunicorn`
2016-03-30T19:03:22.802927+00:00 heroku[run.6010]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-30T19:03:26.232211+00:00 heroku[run.6010]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-30T19:03:26.226737+00:00 heroku[run.6010]: Process exited with status 0
2016-03-30T19:03:30.885840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=8656297c-8a65-4540-8e31-a3a608943ad5 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-30T19:03:30.993104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carlosbeta.herokuapp.com request_id=01437089-65c9-4667-9d64-0ceb6256a4b0 fwd="189.204.187.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Note the error `bash: gunicorn: command not found` - your web dynos won't start because gunicorn is not installed. Make sure your requirements.txt is complete, and contains an entry for gunicorn.

Comment: yes, i solved the error, in the github documentation of heroku i found the answer, thanks https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started